# making required property work in html forms in ie

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Is there any way that I can make the required property of forms work in ie 6+?
I tried in chrome and firefox. It works fine.
I don't wanna use any scripts but I think I have to. Please give me something that would be easy.
html below won't work in ie:

```
<input type="text" name="name" required="required" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many [polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) for HTML5 forms. Check out e.g. [jQuery form shim](http://adodson.com/jquery.form.js/). Test the alternatives in action before deciding between them, because the style of reporting errors (like required field missing) varies.

Comment: I tried jquery form shim, it has got some problems with ie. I don't know which polyfills should i use. Would you recommend one to me? My form has got date and time too

Comment: Thanks, I found enough in polyfills

Comment: @red-cannibal, I noticed that jQuery form shim does not do well with date input in IE, but it handles `required` even on IE 6.